# Getting Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type while trying to click on a button

Tags: c#, angularjs, com-interop

I want to call click event of a button from a web page by using my client c# code.

I can see the element as after doing F12 on the page as:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary form-control btn-block" type="button" 
  ng-click="tranCtrl.retrieveTransactionsList('Go')" ng-disabled="tranCtrl.isLoading">
   Go 
</button>
```

My code works for all the input type buttons but not for the above one.

I have tried multiple classes like `IHTMLButtonElement` but it's not allowing casting of the `_comObject` returned for the button to the `HTMLElement` class.
It throws `invalid cast exception` every time.

```
Ex : Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 
'mshtml.HTMLButtonElement'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface 
call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{3050F51F-98B5-11CF-BB82-
00AA00BDCE0B}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))
```

To download button from web page :

```
IHTMLDocument3 myHTMLDoc3;

myHTMLDoc3 = this.Browser != null ? (IHTMLDocument3)this.Browser.Document : null;
if(myHTMLDoc3!=null)
{
    var buttons = myHTMLDoc3.getElementsByTagName("Button");
    return buttons;
}
```

Below is the typecasting code throwing error :

```
if (objControlElement.GetType().Name == "HTMLInputElement")
{
    htmlInputElement = objControlElement != null ? 
    (HTMLInputElement)objControlElement : null;
    if (htmlInputElement != null)
    {
        htmlInputElement.click();
        executionStatus = true;
    }
}
```

I can see the element as after doing F12 on the page as:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary form-control btn-block" type="button" 
 ng-click="tranCtrl.retrieveTransactionsList('Go')" ng-
 disabled="tranCtrl.isLoading">Go </button>
```

Comment: An HTMLInputElement is a textbox and not a button so click will not work.  The usually a Submit that you use to input data from a text box

Comment: The {guid} is wildly wrong, it is the one for ITargetNotify2.  This can happen when the type library version is not a good match with the actual browser version, which is about always.  Do avoid trouble like this by casting to the interface name, so (IHTMLInputElement).

Comment: Strange because 3050F51F-98B5-11CF-BB82- 00AA00BDCE0B is IID_DispHTMLButtonElement, not  IID_IHTMLButtonElement which is 3050f2bb-98b5-11cf-bb82-00aa00bdce0b. Maybe your code runs too early, or make sure you're running in an STA thread

Comment: What I think is that the below button which I want to click programmatically is somehow of different type :

<button class="btn btn-primary form-control btn-block" type="button" 
 ng-click="tranCtrl.retrieveTransactionsList('Go')" ng-
 disabled="tranCtrl.isLoading">Go </button>

There are other buttons as well on the same page and they are of type <Input type> and I am able to click them programmatically.
Please advise if am heading in right direction.